# Entering UK with Two different Visas?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

Earlier this year I received a multi-entry Business Visitor visa for the UK which is valid until 15 Nov, 2017. I went there for a business meeting that was successful and therefore I've received a Diplomatic Visa(Exempt) for the UK today. The start date for my diplomatic visa is 25 Sep, 2017. My Employer has made the same (25 Sep) my start day at work.

My Question is if I can enter the UK on my initial business visa on the 20th of September so I can sort out my accommodation etc before I begin working on the 25th of Sep?

Originally asked at [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100747/entering-uk-with-two-different-visas).

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but only up until the start date of your work visa, after that your visitor visa is invalid and reportable as a change in circumstances. Whether or not you have to channel hop on 24 Sept is down to the discretion of the IO who lands you on 20 Sept